# Find integers a and b congruent to mod

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Can anyone give me a hint of how to solve this equation

Find integers $a$ and $b$ such that $a + b ≡ a - b \bmod 5$.

I did not go over this in my class. Kindly help me on how to solve this one. Thanks

Comment: The question is equivalent to : find $a,b$ so that $5 $ divides $a+b-a+b=2b$, so take $a$ as arbitrary and $b$ as a multiple of $5$

Comment: $a$ can be anything but $b \equiv 0\ (\text {mod}\ 5).$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a start: note that what you have written implies that $b=0 \text{ (mod 5)}$. To see this, recall that what it *means* to be equal to some residue mod 5 is that $a+b = a-b + 5k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Normal arithmetic reveals that $2b=5k$, which means that $b$ has to be divisible by 5. See if you can figure it out from here!

Answer (score 1):

Subtracting $a$ from both sides and adding $b$ gives
$$2b\equiv 0\mod{5}$$
$$\therefore b=5k$$
For $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. $a$ can take any value in $\mathbb{Z}$ as the equivalence does not depend on $a$.

Answer (score 0):

You could write the congruence in equation form as follows

$$
a+b\equiv a-b\ \bmod 5 \Rightarrow a+b=a-b+k\cdot 5, \ \ k\in\mathbb{Z}
$$

which is equivalent to

$$
2b=k\cdot 5 \Rightarrow 2b\equiv 0 \ \bmod 5.
$$
Now, you can divide here by $2$ since it is relative prime to $5$

so you only need to define $b$ for a such congruence to hold and $b$ should be divisible by  $5$ so $b\in\{5, 15, -10 \}$ just to name a few.